# How to alert child once the parent component's fetch call has been completed? ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, settimeout

**Overview:**

I'm using React and need to know from inside of a child component, when the parent components fetch call has been completed.

The trick is, I must have access to this knowledge inside the child from outside the render method (e.g. componentDidMount() ).

**Background info:**

I need to do this that way I can call a function (which I'm importing), since:

1) the function I want to call will update the state, thus causing an infinite render loop if called inside render

AND

2) the reason why I need to verify the fetch call has been made is because I'm passing the data from the fetch call (via context) into the function as parameters

I make a fetch call in my code and have a variable named "fetched" which is saved as "false" until the fetch is complete, then "fetched" is saved as "true".
Inside the promise, I setTimeout for a second because otherwise the promise will execute before the fetch call is completed, thus the promise will execute before "fetched" can be updated to true. I chose to only "resolve" and never "reject" because I need to know when the fetch call has been completed. So, the "resolve" of the promise is nested in a conditional statement (which returns true, if "fetched" is true).

**Situation:**

1) Among other state values, I have a state property named "fetch" defaulted as "false". The purpose of this state property is to evaluate as "true" once the fetch call has been completed.

2) In my App.js file, I make a fetch call to a database.

3) Inside the ".then" chain, once the fetch call has been accurately made. I then set the state property ("fetched") to true.

4) I have a method named "checkFetch" which return a promise. The promise only resolves and it will only resolve if "fetched" is true, also, everything inside the promise is wrapped in a setTimeout for 1 second (that way I give time for the "fetched" property to be updated).

5) In render(), I pass the "checkFetch" method to context (to be accessed by a child component).

6) In the ViewSchedule.js file (child), I make componentDidMount() an async function. Inside ComponentDidMount I await "checkFetch()" using context.

**QUESTION:**

*This is my issue: if I don't set a timeout inside the promise, then nothing happens (as expected) because the fetch call hasn't been completed so the conditional statement is false.
Is there a better way of implementing this? For instance, I can set the timeout for x amount of seconds, but what if the fetch call were to take longer to complete? That seems like a dangerous practice.*

Below is the code to reference.

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Route, Switch , NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';

import './App.css'

import InfoContext from '../InfoContext';

import ViewSchedule from '../ViewSchedule /ViewSchedule ';


class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      business: [],
      hours: [],
      fetched: false,
    };
  }


   static contextType = InfoContext;


  checkFetch = () => {
    return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
      console.log("waiting...");
      setTimeout(() => {
        if(this.state.fetched === true){
          resolve(true);
        }
      }, 1000);

    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchDatabase();
}

  fetchDatabase = () => {
    Promise.all([
        fetch(`http://localhost:8000/all`,
        {
            headers: {
                'table':'business'
            }
        }),
        fetch(`http://localhost:8000/all`,
        {
            headers: {
                'table':'hours'
            }
        }),
    ])
        .then(([business, hours]) => {
            console.log('responses received!');

            if (!business.ok)
                return business.json().then(e => Promise.reject(e));
            if (!hours.ok)
                return hours.json().then(e => Promise.reject(e));

            return Promise.all([business.json(), hours.json()]);
        })
        .then( ([business, hours]) => {

            //fetch has been completed and the state has been updated so set "fetched" to true
            this.setState({business, hours, fetched: true});


        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error({error});
        });
  }

  render(){

    return (
      <InfoContext.Provider value={{businessData: this.state.business,
        dayData: this.state.hours, fetched: this.state.fetched,
        /* METHODS */
        checkFetch: this.checkFetch}}>

        <div className="container">

          <main role="main">

            {/* MAIN TEXT SECTION */}
            <Switch>

              //deleted all the nonessential routes/imports/methods so that this wouldn't be cluttered

              <Route exact path='/view' component={ViewSchedule } />

            </Switch>

          </main>

        </div>
    </InfoContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

ViewSchedule.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

import { Container, Row, Col } from 'react-grid-system';

import './ViewSchedule.css';

import {InfoContext } from '../InfoContext';

//require function "call"

const logic = require('../test');



class ViewSchedule extends React.Component{ 

    static contextType = InfoContext;


    async componentDidMount(){

        try{
            let fetched = await this.context.checkFetch();

            // call(this.context.business)

        } catch (err){
            console.log('ERROR in PROMISE: ',err)
        }


    }

    render(){

        return(

        <div className='grid-container'>
            <p>Content removed for testing purposes</p>
        </div>
        );
    }
}


export default ViewSchedule;
```

InfoContext.js

```
import React, { createContext, Component} from 'react';

export const InfoContext = createContext({
    businessData: null,
    employeeData: null, dayData: null,
    laborData: null,
    scheduleData: null,
    fetched: null,
    checkFetch: () => {

    },
    updateEmployees: () => {

    },

});

export default InfoContext;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to alert a child when something happens in the parent, you use refs.

Here's a simple example code that will help you understand this pattern:

```js
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
    onParentFetchFinished(response) {
        // This function is called when parent component finished fetching
    }

    render() {
        return null;
    }
}

class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.childComponentRef = React.createRef();
    }

    onClick = () => {
        fetch('someurl').then(response => {
            this.childComponentRef.current.onParentFetchFinished(response);
        });
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>Start fetching</button>
        <ChildComponent ref={this.childComponentRef} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ahhh! Thank you! I wasn’t aware of this, this is the kind of answer I was looking for! I’ll check that out when I get home.